# How to detect if user chooses Nvidia overlay when screen sharing in web app?

Tags: web-applications, webrtc, mediastream, screensharing

In my app, I require users to share their entire screen to proceed to the next step by checking if `trackSettings.displaySurface == "monitor"`.

When choosing what to share, Nvidia overlay shows up as one of the Window options (at least on Chrome, Firefox doesn't categorize these choices), but if picked, it still somehow passes the check mentioned above.

On top of that, choosing the Nvidia overlay makes users share a black screen. I don't want to allow or even risk some of the users sharing a black screen and proceed.

How can I detect and reject the overlay if a user tries to choose it?